# Check if a Key exists in array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Objects:

```
{
    "groceries": [{
        "fruit": "orange"
    }, {
        "fruit": "apple"
    }, {
        "vegetable": "carrot"
    }]
}
```

I want to check if this array has a key called `vegetable`. If so, `return true` else `return false` using JavaScript

```
groceries.find(function(ele) {
          return (Object.keys(ele).indexOf('vegetable') !== -1);
        });
```

Not sure if there is an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `in`

```js
const object = {
    "groceries": [{
        "fruit": "orange"
    }, {
        "fruit": "apple"
    }, {
        "vegetable": "carrot"
    }]
}

console.log(object.groceries.some(item => 'vegetable' in item))
```

Comment: nice ... `item.hasOwnProperty('vegetable')` may be an alternative.

Comment: [`hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is a recommended replacement for `hasOwnProperty` and I guess it can work even better than `in` here

Comment: @KonradLinkowski is `item['vegetable']` could be enough too?

Comment: @zb22 `{ vegetable:  0 }` would return `false` for `item['vegetable']`, but it clearly exists. so depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return true or false, you should use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and not find. And you can avoid checking the keys by using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or [hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn).

```js
var data = {
    "groceries": [{
        "fruit": "orange"
    }, {
        "fruit": "apple"
    }, {
        "vegetable": "carrot"
    }]
}

const result = data.groceries.some(o => o.hasOwnProperty('vegetable'))
console.log(result);

const result2 = data.groceries.some(o => Object.hasOwn(o, 'vegetable'))
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
Object.keys(e)
```

You will obtain an array, may be you have to do only this ?

```
Object.keys(e)[0]
```

Because you have only one element. And adapt it if you change your array afterwards...
So your code becomes :

```
groceries.find(e => {
    return (Object.keys(e)[0] === 'vegetable')
});
```